# JsHint Exit Code(s)

Tags: makefile, jshint

I am using JsHint in a Makefile for a project I am working on and the errors that are reported are not being noticed by Make. Is there a way to capture the error and not hard exit the execution of Make? Below is a sample Makefile:

```
all: css js

css:
    compass compile

hint:
    jshint js/*.js

js: hint
    uglify js/*.js
```

So, for example, the `hint` target is showing errors but is doing a hard exit and not informing Make that it exited.

I might not be using the correct terms for things and I apologize.

Comment: Presumably `jshint` is not exiting with a non-zero exit code when it fails.  Can you check with `jshint js/*.js ; echo $?`?

Comment: That was my first assumption too but when I run jshint with a file with exactly one error it is reported and the error code output by `echo $?` is 2.

Comment: I'm also getting error 2

Answer (score 1):

Use a hyphen before the recipe…

```
hint:
    -jshint js/*.js
```